# Showing an image in random position with setInterval using p5.js

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use setInterval within a class to show and hide an image at set times using set Interval. The code below is as far as I got. Thanks in advance

```
class Logo{
    constructor(_x,_y,_img){
        this.img = _img;
        this.imgX = _x;
        this.imgY = _y;
        this.rotate = 0;
        this.imgWidth = this.img.width;
        this.imgHeight = this.img.height;
    }


    start(){

        setInterval(()  => this.update, 1000)


    }

    update(){
        image(this.img,this.imgX,this.imgY)
        this.img.resize(height*.75,0)
    }


}
```

Comment: What's your question? What are you confused about?

Comment: Terrible communication here. Basically, the code does not work. The image does not appear at random position every 1000 milliseconds

Comment: Why would you expect this to work? When do you call `checkEdges()`? Why are you using `setInterval()` with P5.js at all? You should just use P5.js timing instead.

Comment: Thanks for your continued interest. The check edges function was a bit of a red herring, I've removed it now. I wanted to use javascript's native functions for this particular piece of code.

Comment: To whomever voted to remove the `p5.js` from this post, I think that it _is_ a p5 question, it's just their current code isn't implementing it. So really the answer _should_ involve p5 and therefore the tag should stick.